# Is a 4x4x18' enough to support this span. 12'x13' room. Ridge beam supported each end with a 13' open span

Tags: roof, structural

[image]

Screened in room. Ridge beam recommendation?

Comment: I think I understand what you’re asking, but can you please clarify your question and its context in the body of your posting?

Comment: I mean at a glance it looks way too flimsy.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on snow load, if any, “dead load” (composition of roof structure), species of wood, grade of beam, etc., I’d use a 4x8...minimum...for a 13’ span.

Answer (score 1):

The Southern Forest Products Association publishes [Souther Pine Size Selection Tables](http://www.southernpine.com/app/uploads/SS_15-20L.pdf) that will help with this question.  There are different tables for different snow loads etc.  The tables spans start at 10' x 16', which requires a minimum built-up beam of two 2x12's for the ridge beam.  A 4x4 is quite a bit less supportive and will likely sag.

It is possible that additional support can be had by adding framing to turn the rafters into trusses etc., but that is a more complicated question.

Comment: Based on a cursory read of the tables, the absolute minimum would be 4x12 for an 18' ridge beam.